# Get display independent browser zoom level

Tags: javascript, windows, browser, zooming, scaling

Due to application specific requirements I need to reliably determine the browsers zoom level.

## Circumstances

Unfortunantely I only found `window.devicePixelRatio` which mixes multiple values.

1. Windows Display scaling:
   [image]
2. window.devicePixelRatio:
   [image]
3. Chrome zoomed in:
   [image]
4. window.devicePixelRatio:
   [image]

## Example

You can reproduce this behavior using this simplistic [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y5L4307k/).

## Question

How does one distinguish between these two zoom levels?
I need to identify at at whenever the browser reaches 100% browser zoom level. (Srolling in and out).
Is it possible to only track the browsers values?

Thank you

Comment: Check https://www.sitelint.com/blog/detect-browser-zoom-level/